# Print JSON Data Individually

Tags: php, ajax, json, echo

I have an AJAX Request, that essentially queries a database then posts the data back to the JS, however I can't print individual bits of data.

My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '_process/offerrespres.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                msgid: msgid,
                usrid: usrid
            },
            success: function(){
                console.log(JSON.parse(data.pro_name));
                console.log(data.accept_decline);
            }
        });
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
if ($_POST) {
$msgid = mysql_escape_string($_POST['msgid']);
$usrid = mysql_escape_string($_POST['usrid']);  
$getmsgq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking_requests WHERE receiver_id = '$usrid' AND msg_id = '$msgid'");
$getmsg_info = mysql_fetch_array($getmsgq); 
$data['success'] = true;
$data['date_sent'] = $getmsg_info['date_sent'];
$data['pro_name'] = $getmsg_info['pro_name'];
$data['accept_decline'] = $getmsg_info['accept_decline'];
}
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close();
?>
```

As you can see I've tried this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data.pro_name));
console.log(data.accept_decline);
```

the error in the console says "data not defined". The output from the PHP file is correct and how it should be, I just can't print one single piece of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your callback function isn't accepting the return data as an argument

The line that reads `success: function(){` should be `success: function(data){`

Also, the `true` isn't needed in your call to `header("Content-Type: application/json", true);`. The default action of this function is to replace headers, so `true` is already implied. That argument is only necessary if you don't want to replace the previous `Content-Type`. Makes no difference to your code, just a tip.

Comment: Thank you - another simple thing. Worked a treat. also, data.pro_name worked correctly (without the JSON.parse)

Comment: @Steve_M You're welcome. please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue so others will know that question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the data variable in the success function.
It should be:

```
success: function(data){
   console.log(JSON.parse(data.pro_name));
   console.log(data.accept_decline);
}
```